# MSAF analytics for windows phone marketplace test kit fail

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have implemented the Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework with google analytics and according to the documentation i have included this code snippet in App.xaml

with some modifications i.e google analytics id

```
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
 <!-- The order of these services is important -->
 <shell:PhoneApplicationService/>
 <local:TestAppService/>
 <mwa:WebAnalyticsService>
   <mwa:WebAnalyticsService.Services>
     <ga:GoogleAnalytics WebPropertyId="UA-12345-1"/>
   </mwa:WebAnalyticsService.Services>
 </mwa:WebAnalyticsService>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

The code is working great at debug mode but when i m testing with the marketplace test kit the test fails at the back button functionality.

For every page i get the error : pressing the back button does not close the dialog box

If i delete this code from App.xaml then it passes the marketplace test.But then i suppose i cannot have analytics.So what should i do? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You could always just avoid MSAF entirely and use this open source google analytics framework:
http://codecube.net/2012/02/googleanalyticstracker-for-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the code of microsoft analytics framework for silverlight, 
I have found a issue in
projectname- Microsoft.WebAnalytics.WP7, filename-WebAnalyticsService.cs.
In this file they are opening a popup and not closing it in lifetime of the 
object. Because of this we are getting error "pressing the back button does 
not close the dialog box".

As I have tried, closing the pop-up works fine and doesn't show the error.

But I am  not sure for what purpose they are opening the popup and not 
closing it. And whether closing the popup have dependencies on other 
projects or files. And where to close the popup in the file.

Comment: how did you manage to pass the validation? at which point did you close the popup for the marketplace validation to work? i tried closing it on backkeypress to no avail.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's what I did in the end (its always closed now). I just thought you might have found a way to open and close it at the "correct" point of time. Surely, there must be some functionality associated to the page being open?